# MySQL - Number assignment according name ordering

Tags: mysql, sql

My original table

STUDENTS

```
    id |    Name     |    Class    |  Order Number |    
   32  |    Xavier   | 10A         | 0             |
   10  |    Mary     | 10B         | 0             |
   35  |    Mandy    | 10B         | 0             |
    4  |    Ruby     | 10A         | 0             |
   12  |    Ben      | 10A         | 0             |
   27  |    Ben      | 10B         | 0             |
```

And a I need the table to be transformed this way:

STUDENTS

```
    id |    Name     |    Class    |  Order Number |    
   12  |    Ben      | 10A         | 1             |  
    4  |    Ruby     | 10A         | 2             |
   32  |    Xavier   | 10A         | 3             |
   27  |    Ben      | 10B         | 1             | 
   35  |    Mandy    | 10B         | 2             |
   10  |    Mary     | 10B         | 3             |
```

How can i do that?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function along with the following `ORDER BY` clause

```
 SELECT id, name, class, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY class ORDER BY name) AS "Order Number"
   FROM `students`
  ORDER BY class, name
```

if DB version is 8+

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Barbaros!